# Decompose A Picture With PowerPoint Shapes

Tags: image, ms-office, powerpoint, visio

Kind of a weird question for you today. I was requested to take a IMAGE like the following (small portion of a rather big diagram)...

[image]

And make it into an editable diagram. I was wondering if there was anyway to decompose into PowerPoint shapes to be able to edit the lines, text, color of boxes, etc. The diagram was created in PowerPoint, then was created into a image, while the PowerPoint diagram was deleted.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do this exact thing for another reason. The closest I could get was to import the image into Photoshop or Adobe Acrobat. These programs can detect the text. Sometimes Acrobat detected text better, but to change the shapes it still had to go to Photoshop. Then, I put the text on its own layer. Next, I redrew the shapes on top of the original. Finally, I deleted the original image, leaving me with the text layers on top of the shape layers on top of a background layer(I prefer it to be alpha channel). Then any edits can be made as desired.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll certainly give that a try! Downloading Photoshop now. Was it able to detect lines?

Comment: Not in my experience. I just redrew them.